# Diference between two JSONs

Tags: java, json, javabeans

I'm using spring MVC to implement Web-Service that return the Object `Response`

class JAVA Reponse

```
   @XmlRootElement(name="response")
        public class Response {

        private String request ;
        private List<ListResponse> responses;

         }
```

class JAVA ListResponse

```
  @XmlRootElement(name="response")
    public class ListResponse {

    private String param ;
    private List<Param> values;

     }
```

class JAVA Param

```
  public class Param {
    private String ID;
    private String VALUE;
    private String LIBELLE;  
    }
```

The result of web service was this JSON :

```
{
 "request": "DEP",
 "response": {
   "param": "DEP",
   "values": [
     {
       "ID": 1000016,
       "LIBELLE": "AIN",
       "VALUE": "010"
     }
   ]
 }
}
```

But this is not good for me, i want Reponse to be `List`, like this

```
{  
   "request":"DEP",
   "response":[  
      {  
         "param":"DEP",
         "values":[  
            {  
               "ID":1000016,
               "LIBELLE":"AIN",
               "VALUE":"010"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

SO, any solution for this ??

Comment: Why don't you change your `List<ListResponse> responses` to `ListResponse response`

Comment: jackson actually generates what you want, I'd suggest removing the  @XmlRootElement(name="response") from your `ListResponse`, there is probably something else going on because with the code posted here, you should get the output you want